# "Join this Community" button not working

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts

Picking out a public beta from https://stackexchange.com/sites, I reach the site's main page and click "Join this community" in the upper right.  The page refreshes, but still shows "Join this community" and I haven't apparently joined.

---

The workaround is to click "Ask a Question," then in the lower left click "Log In," at which point I see:

> **Confirm Your New Account**
>
> You are about to create a new account on Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange using a login from
> Stack Exchange
>
> We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.

Then there's a big orange button which reads "Confirm and Create this Account" and clicking on that works as expected.

However, "join this community" should also work.

I'm logged in with SE and SE only (i.e. not authenticating with Facebook or Google).

Comment: Interesting. When did you try this?

Comment: A few minutes before posting the question, and again just now.